# How do I trim "&nbsp;" characters from text?

Tags: mysql, ruby, trim

I am scraping a webpage and inserting data from the page to MySQL. The text that I am inserting contains:

```
&nbsp; my text
&nbsp; 89
```

Because of this space-like character, my text and integer data is not being properly inserted into MySQL. How do I trim this character from a variable, like `mydata`?

Comment: For the future, keep this in mind: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to trim only the beginning of the string, you can simply use `sub`:

```
"&nbsp; my text".sub(/^(&nbsp;|\s)+/, '')
 => "my text"
```

If you need both ends stripped, try this:

```
"&nbsp; my text   &nbsp;    ".sub(/^(&nbsp;|\s)*(.*?)(&nbsp;|\s)*$/, '\2')
=> "my text"
```

Alternatively:

```
"&nbsp; my text   &nbsp;    ".gsub("&nbsp;", "").strip
 => "my text"
```

Comment: as i mentioned in comment to above answer in ruby this multibyte character is displayed as `whitespace` not `&nbsp;` so `.gsub("&nbsp;", "")` ain't working also replacing with that multibyte character gives syntax error.

Comment: Which version of Ruby You use? If it's 1.9.3, try adding this at the beginning of file:

# encoding: UTF-8

If You need more help, we need to see more of Your code.

Comment: its ruby 1.9.3p448 (2013-06-27) [i386-mingw32]. its a lengthy code which part do you need variable, source page scrapping or mysql query?

Comment: Have You tried adding encoding first? Probably the problem is in Your scraping.

Comment: Simply add: `#encoding: UTF-8` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: `#{data.text[1..data.text.length]` this worked for me but this is just a temporary shortcut but i am still waiting if someone would suggest a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way i found for this issue

```
str.gsub(/[[:space:]]/, '')
```